# Submit A Angular Form Via the Local Network

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have created an angular project. I launch it on the local network with the command `ng serve --host 0.0.0`
When I open my project in the browser everything goes well. I submit my form and I receive the data on the Spring server side.
but when I open the form page on the phone it is displayed but when I submit the form nothing happens on the server.

What is the problem please?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does your phone connected to the same wifi as your pc ? and your phone can't interact with localhost, just check the back-end host